# Error while invoking performSegue function

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I could call my `performSegue` outside alamofire validation handler. but I want to segue after the alamofire request is succeeded

here is my code

```
Alamofire.request("link", method: .post, parameters: parameters!, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "successRegistration", sender: Any?)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

the problem is in the following line

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "successRegistration", sender: Any?)
```

it shows me the following error

> expected member name or constructor call after type name

and xcode gives me two fixes, one is to change `Any?` to `Any?()` which gives me another error as shown below:

> cannot invoke initializer for type 'Any?' with no arguments

the other fix is to change `Any?` to `Any?.self` and this gives me another error show below:

> Implicit use of 'self' in closure, use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

the same problem (above) occurs when I change `Any?` to `nil`

What is causing this error? (knowing that the `performSegue` function works fine outside Alamofire when I change `Any?` to `nil` )

Comment: I guess you can do things. 1. Try 'self' here, self.performSeque 2. Perform segue in main queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("successRegistration", sender: nil)
```

try to use "self" before performSegue function.

Comment: In swift 3, 
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successRegistration", sender: nil)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you pass "Any?" as argument. It's similar to data type like Int or Bool. If you want pass nothing just send nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successRegistration", sender: nil)
```

Some notes:

- inside a closure, which you are, you always need to use `self` to reference the outer object. In your case, that would be the `UIViewControlller`.
- `Any` is a type name (a protocol) and not a value. To specify "empty" values, use `nil` instead. Use `Any` as a *type* for general values, with no defined/known type.